what is the default launcher.json VSCode on MAUIAPP for Android Device Target?
I just curious from the MAUIAPP  perspective of Hello world (inside VSCODE). Everything is fine under window execution.
But when i tried to use Real Device as my target. From here : link. In which i already connect to the device using adb command succsefully. But here in VSCode everytime i Click the button of Run & Debug.... The VSCode said, there is something wrong in json file.

As you can see on the bottom right corner, the Device is already connected.
But there's something error on the Launcher. In which i dont know.

Can anybody show me the real json file content that targeting real device. What are the fixed format (or correct pattern) actually used?
Thanks in advance hope this enlight others MAUIApp developers as well.
